# Entity Framework Get Rows Part by Part

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I want to get data with using the Entity Framework. For example, the first 100 data then the second 100 data. How can I do that?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. To improve your chances of getting help, please read the [guidance on how to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). As for your question, what have you tried? Have you looked at the LINQ `Skip` and `Take` operators?

Comment: The search term you are looking for is *paging*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this :

```
   using(yourDbContext dc = new yourDbContext)
   {
     var list = ( from ro in dc.yourTable orderby ro.order select ro).Take(100);
     //Or var list = ( from ro in dc.yourTable orderby ro.order select ro).Skip(100).Take(100);
   }
```